# Qark reports a PendingIntent security issue on java files: zzaup, zzst, zze, MediaButtonReceiver, TaskStackBuilder

Tags: java, android, security, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I'm working on an already existing app and I had to test the code security vulnerabilities using [QARK](https://github.com/linkedin/qark) (Quick Android Review Kit).

When I run this tool it reports this problems related to Pending Intents:
In these Java classes:
 
  - myApp/classes_dex2jar/com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaup.java
  - myApp/classes_dex2jar/com/google/android/gms/internal/zzst.java
  - myApp/classes_dex2jar/com/google/android/gms/common/zze.java
  - myApp/classes_dex2jar/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.java
  - myApp/classes_dex2jar/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.java

With the same warning:

> Implicit Intent: localIntent used to create instance of PendingIntent. A malicious application could potentially intercept, redirect and/or modify (in a limited manner) this Intent. Pending Intents retain the UID of your application and all related permissions, allowing another application to act as yours.
>   File: myApp/classes_dex2jar/[folder structure for each java class listed above].java
>   More details: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/android/DRD21-J.+Always+pass+explicit+intents+to+a+PendingIntent

[image: Error example]

I really have no idea what to do.
In my code there isn't any of these classes, neither PendingIntent.
  (Only 1 implicit intent to open a simple link in browser, nothing else!)

Any suggestion???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself so that I can help those who need it in the future.

Simply, the report that was given to me was generated with an **old** version of QARK (beginning of July **2018**, version **1.2**, the current one is **4.0**.)

Searching on the internet I found [this issue](https://github.com/linkedin/qark/issues/315) (now closed) in which it is said that:

> "The blog posts are old and use the release version of QARK. In the newer version (with more checks, faster execution, and **less false positives**) we have a simple report for now. [...]".

Good luck to all and good development!